# How to throw a value when exiting recursive edit (without using setq)

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to throw a value when exiting recursive edit without using `setq`?

The functions below work correctly with `setq`, however, my goal is to eliminate unnecessary global variables (if possible) -- especially file names -- and use `let` bound variables instead.  In the context of throwing a value when exiting recursive edit, however, I have been unable to devise a method that does not use a global variable for the file name.

In this example, I am using `lawlist-save-as` in conjunction with `dired-read-file-name` to enter dired-mode and select a file name or a path.  Pressing the enter key on a file name selects a file.  Pressing the enter key on a directory name or the two (2) dots moves up one directory.  Pressing the enter key on the line with just one (1) dot, means select only the path in the current directory.  The value of the file name or path is passed back to the function `lawlist-save-as` through *the last line of `dired-read-file-name`*.

[Although not necessary for this example (but just in case anyone is curious), getting marked files with `(dired-get-marked-files)` is used for a different situation, such as attaching multiple files to an e-mail using Wanderlust -- in which case, I use the condition `((listp lawlist-filename) (throw 'exit nil))`.  And, of course, opening a file is self-explanatory -- used for a situation when dired-mode is entered regularly and then just pressing the return key on a file to be opened.]

```
(require 'dired)
(defvar lawlist-filename nil)
(defvar save-as-buffer-filename nil)
(defvar save-as-variable nil)
(defvar dired-buffer-name nil)

(defun dired-read-file-name (&optional directory)
  (let ((working-buffer (buffer-name)))
    (if directory
      (dired directory)
    (dired nil))
    (let ((dired-buffer-name (buffer-name)))
      (if save-as-buffer-filename
        (progn
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (re-search-forward (file-name-nondirectory save-as-buffer-filename) nil t)))
      (recursive-edit)
      (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)
      (switch-to-buffer working-buffer)
      lawlist-filename)))

;; select file or directory.
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<return>") (lambda () (interactive)
  (setq lawlist-filename
    (if (or (re-search-backward "^*" nil t)
            (re-search-forward "^*" nil t))
      (dired-get-marked-files)
      (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
  (cond
    ((listp lawlist-filename)
      (throw 'exit nil))
    ;; open file
    ((and (not (file-directory-p lawlist-filename))
        (file-exists-p lawlist-filename)
        (not (equal lawlist-filename (concat (file-name-directory lawlist-filename) ".")))
        (not save-as-variable))
      (find-file lawlist-filename))
    ;; save-as
    ((and (not (file-directory-p lawlist-filename))
        (file-exists-p lawlist-filename)
        (not (equal lawlist-filename (concat (file-name-directory lawlist-filename) "."))))
      (throw 'exit nil))
    ;; go up one directory
    ((and (file-directory-p lawlist-filename)
        (not (equal lawlist-filename (concat (file-name-directory lawlist-filename) "."))))
      (setq dired-buffer-name (buffer-name))
      (dired-find-file)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (re-search-forward " \\.\\.$" nil t)
      (kill-buffer dired-buffer-name)
      (setq dired-buffer-name (buffer-name)))
    ;; only use current path for save-as situation.
    ((and (equal lawlist-filename (concat (file-name-directory lawlist-filename) "."))
        save-as-variable)
      (setq lawlist-filename (expand-file-name default-directory))
      (throw 'exit nil)) )))

(defun lawlist-save-as ()
(interactive)
  (setq save-as-variable t)
  (if (buffer-file-name)
    (setq save-as-buffer-filename (buffer-file-name)))
  (let ((proposed-filename (dired-read-file-name)))
    (when proposed-filename ;; needed if aborting recursive-edit
      (setq save-as-variable nil)
      (let ((save-as-filename (read-string "Save-As:  "
        (concat proposed-filename (when (file-directory-p proposed-filename) (buffer-name))))))
      (setq save-as-buffer-filename nil)
      (when (and save-as-filename (file-exists-p save-as-filename))
        (or (y-or-n-p (format "File `%s' exists; overwrite? " save-as-filename))
          (error "Canceled")))
      (set-visited-file-name save-as-filename)
      (set-buffer-modified-p t)
      (and (buffer-file-name)
           (file-writable-p buffer-file-name)
           (setq buffer-read-only nil))
      (save-buffer)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`recursive-edit` is just a function that runs a command loop. All stuff that is valid for lisp applies.
So if you encapsulate `recursive-edit` into a `let` which locally binds some variable, say `test`, and if you `setq` this variable during the recursive edit session this variable is just set locally in the scope of the `let`.

Example:
Run the following with <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>:

```
(let (test)
    (recursive-edit)
    (message "test=%S" test))
```

You will be in the command loop of the recursive edit. Then set `test` via <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(setq test "That is my test.")`.
Afterwards press <kbd>M-C-c</kbd> to exit the recursive edit session.
The message `test=\"That is my test.\"` is be printed out but the symbol `test` is still unbound.

Comment: Your example works, and applying that to my working example also works.  Would it be possible for you to please do me the favor of explaining what `(test)` means -- does that mean we are defining a `let` bound variable named `test` with a value of `nil`?  Its just that I've never seen a `let` bound variable all by itself, and I have also never seen a `let` bound variable with only one pair of surrounding parenthesis.

Comment: That is a simple one since I just have to copy the help for `(let VARLIST BODY)`. Especially, the part about `VARLIST` is interesting for you. Output of `C-h f let`: Bind variables according to VARLIST then eval BODY.
The value of the last form in BODY is returned.
Each element of VARLIST is a symbol (which is bound to nil)
or a list (SYMBOL VALUEFORM) (which binds SYMBOL to the value of VALUEFORM).
All the VALUEFORMs are evalled before any symbols are bound.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much for resolving the issue and for teaching me how to use `setq` locally for the duration of a function.

Comment: I learned another lesson today and wanted to add a comment to this thread.  A library containing `-*- lexical-binding: t -*-` at the outset prevents setting a let-bound variable during recursive edit (e.g., with `setq . . .`) if that function containing the let-bound variable is anywhere underneath that heading within the same library.  I had copied an entire library and made custom edits when I discovered this issue.